# How to keep some information about database not in special table (SQLite)

Tags: database, sqlite, metadata

We need to keep in database following information **about database**:

1. Name;
2. Author;
3. Short decription;

I can just use special table for it (id, name_property, content). But maybe there is some nice tricks for it?

Comment: I change text of question: we need to keep information about database. I thought that there is some tricks for it to avoid using additional table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to store information in a database, use a table. That's what they are for.

EDIT:

SQLite has no notion of documenting a table. A table's creator and textual description are simply not things implemented in SQLite. Sorry. Your best bet would be a table on its own that carries that information.

Comment: Your minus is unnecessary, because it is not so explicitly. For example in MySQL I can add comment to tables:`CREATE TABLE 'temp' (
  'name' int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COMMENT='Author: sun; Description: test table;';`

Comment: @QueueOverflow Well, you adding "about the database" changes the question completely. And it was not my minus. Someone else did that.

Comment: OK, sorry. It was a just pity. I forgot write this string, because it was in title of question.

Comment: I created additional table. Thanks for answer.